# Facebook Messenger apps repeated calls to webhook complicating my debug procedures

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I'm currently developing my fist bot.

When I add a breakpoint somewhere in the code of my bot application, send a message from my Facebook page, and debugger stops at that point, after some seconds the debugger stops at that point again, making the debug procedure very complicated.

I understand this happens since I didn't acknowledge the message was received by returning a status code 200, and for that reason my Facebook Messenger application keeps sending the same request.

Is there a way to set up my Facebook Messenger application so that it only calls my webhook once, or to increase the period of time my webhook is called?

Otherwise, are there any suggestions overcome this?

Comment: Neither of those two is possible.

Comment: I was hopping some of the subscription fields would help with that...

Comment: No, via those you only specify what kind of data you want updates about.

Comment: @amuramoto that was the only option I thought of before posting this question, but as you said it was the only way to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: @RedEagle I've reposted my comment as an answer so others can find it later if needed.

Comment: Marked it as the correct answer. Than you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only option really is to send the 200 as soon as the webhook receives a message while you are debugging, so that you can step through any of your message processing.